# Asp.net pages -> session expired when its in use in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application session will automatically expired when application is in still running mode.

> In my page all hits are happens through ajax calls only.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Session timeouts are set to expire in ASP.NET in 20 minutes. To increase the timeout or expiry you should change the timeout attribute for SessionState in the web.config file

```
<sessionState  timeout="40" />
```

Note that if you are using Forms authentication, the Forms timeout setting will log the user out after the set timeout period so you will also have to adjust this attribute:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="40"/>
    </authentication>
```

Use the following link for Session Timeout with popup alert message.

[Session Timeout Example](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/06/15/asp-net-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout.aspx)